# How to count and show number of inner elements for every treetable branch?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, grouping, webix

I have a grouped (by users' lastnames) TreeTable (Webix). Here's the config:

```
columns:[
  { id:"lastname", template:function(obj, common){      
    return common.icon(obj, common)+obj.lastname
  } }
],
scheme:{
  $group:{ 
    by:function(obj){  
      return obj.lastname.substring(0,1); // grouping by first letter
    },
    map:{ 
      lastname:[function(obj){        
        return obj.lastname.substring(0,1); 
      }]
    }
  }
},
```

**[The snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/9d35cad1)** (the same config, another dataset)

With the `map` property `template` shows the first letter as the branch title. But I can't figure out how to show the count of the items in each branch. Something like

- A (18)
- B (5)

and so on. How to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to customize the template function of your columns such that for obj.$level==1 in the group it shows the count of elements (obj.$count) along with the title and for others it shows only the title. The required code is below :

```
webix.ui({
view:"treetable", 
id:"treetable",
columns:[
    { 
        id:"title", header:"Film title", width:250, 
        template:function(obj, common){      
            if(obj.$level == 1){
                return common.icon(obj, common)+ obj.title + " ( " + obj.$count + " ) " ;
            }
            else{
                return common.icon(obj, common)+ obj.title ;         
            }
        } 
    }
]
/****Your Code***/
});
```